# Can you help me refactor this piece of clojure code to produce a seq?

Tags: refactoring, clojure

I want to produce a seq that I can later do a (map) over. It should look like this:

```
((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) ... (7 7))
```

The piece of code I have to do it right now seems very, very ugly to produce such a simple result. I need some help getting this straight.

```
(loop [y 0 x 0 args (list)]  
  (if (and (= y 7) (= x 7))  
    (reverse (conj args (list y x)))  
    (if (= x 7)  
    (recur (+ y 1) 0 (conj args (list y x)))  
    (recur y (+ x 1) (conj args (list y x))))))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(let [my-range (range 0 8)]
  (for [i my-range
        j my-range]
      (list i j)))


=> ((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) (0 4) (0 5) (0 6) (0 7)
    (1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5) (1 6) (1 7)
    ...
    (7 0) (7 1) (7 2) (7 3) (7 4) (7 5) (7 6) (7 7))
```

---

for is like doseq, but it collects results:

```
(for   [i [1 2 3]] i)           => (1 2 3)
(doseq [i [1 2 3]] (print i))   => nil
```

Comment: shorter version:

(for [i (range 8) j (range 8)] (list i j))

Answer (score 5):

There's a library function that does that:

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.combinatorics])
(cartesian-product (range 0 8) (range 0 8))
```